# Assembly code registers and reallocation of associated values

Tags: assembly

**Question:**

My understanding is that registers `EAX,EBX,ECX,EDX` are "general purpose" and more or less interchangeable as per this [link](http://www.hep.wisc.edu/~pinghc/x86AssmTutorial.htm).  So why is it that when I exchange the operands/values as follows in the code below it does not print `"Hello World!"` anymore.

**Test:**

Switch the values/operands following `mov` for registers `edx` and `ecx` below.

```
mov edx,13
mov ecx,msg
```

to

```
mov edx,msg
mov ecx,13
```

**Result:**

The breaks the code.  I obviously have misunderstood how this works so would appreciate some guidance.  Ultimately I am trying to gain a better understanding of why and how certain registers are used.

**Code sample:**

Original working code taken from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/assembly_programming/index.htm):

```
section .text
    global _start   ;must be declared for linker (ld)
_start:             ;tells linker entry point
    mov edx,13      ;message length
    mov ecx,msg     ;message to write
    mov ebx,1       ;file descriptor (stdout)
    mov eax,4     ;system call number (sys_write)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

    mov eax,1       ;system call number (sys_exit)
    int 0x80        ;call kernel

section .data
msg db 'Hello, world!', 0xa  ;string to be printed
len equ $ - msg     ;length of the string
```

Comment: Each of them is 32 bits. If you set `edx` to bits based on numeric value `13` or on `msg` symbol (which is just a number too), the CPU has no idea which is which and why, all it does "see" are the 32 bits of the register set to 32 0/1 values. All the logical meaning of such value is given by the following code using the value, either as unsigned length, or signed offset, or memory address to string, or four characters of ASCII string, or just separate 32 bit values,  or anything else the programmer will make up of it. Nothing of that is encoded in the register itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The program breaks *because* those registers are interchangeable: their meaning is an agreement between the part of the code that writes to them, and the part that reads from them.

In your case, `int 0x80` hands control to a kernel process which expects to read certain values from those registers. As the comments on the original code say, it expects to read:

- system call number from `eax` (4 = sys_write)
- file descriptor from `ebx` (1 = stdout)
- a pointer to the start of the string from `ecx`
- the length of the string from `edx`

If you swap the values around, *it has no way of knowing you have done so*; so it reads value 13 from `ecx`, and assumes that's where your string starts, then reads a memory address from `edx` and assumes that's the length of your string.

In terms of a higher-level language, it's like you've changed this:

```
sys_call(sys_write, stdout, msg_address, 13);
```

to this:

```
sys_call(sys_write, stdout, 13, msg_address);
```

Answer (score 2):

The registers may be used equally, but they don't necessarily have the same meaning.  The system calls each assign a different meaning to them:

- `int 0x80` requires that `eax` is used to determine which system call you're invoking.
- `sys_write` (an `eax` of 4) requires that `ebx` hold a file descriptor, `ecx` hold the character buffer, and `edx` hold the length.

If you swap around the values, you sure as heck won't get the right result, because it's the same as if you passed values in the wrong positions to a function; it won't get what it's expecting.

In your own code, you can use them however you want (that's what "interchangeable" really means on that introductory page), but when you invoke other code, you have to follow whatever rules that other code may have set up.